# If you bottle space with something inside does it still float when brought back to Earth?

Tags: experimental-physics

If you put something like a penny in a jar in space and brought it back to earth would the penny still float like in space?

Comment: Have you thought about what might happen?  Do you have any guesses?  We could probably give a more insightful answer if we understood what your thoughts on the experiment were.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> would the penny still float like in space?

Your main misunderstanding is in thinking that, in space, things float because they are in vacuum. Instead, things "float" because the gravitation of the earth is counterbalanced by the movement of the spacecraft in orbit. When you bring them back to earth, that balance no longer applies and the penny will drop.

If you have watched videos from inside the International Space Station, you may have noticed that the astronauts and objects they manipulate also float. Yet I can assure you the astronauts are not in vacuum. If they were they would be in extreme discomfort - and very dead after a minute or so.

Comment: I know the cabin is pressurized. So your saying you don't float in space unless you're going fast?

Comment: Correct. Say you went at 1000 km/h, straight up to 1000km, without fast horizontal movement. If you then turned the engine of, you'd coast to a stop, and fall straight back down. Put a cannon on a very high mountain. As you use more and more powder, the cannonball flies further and further, until it eventually goes so fast (7 km/s) that it keeps missing the ground. Then it's in orbit.

Comment: That makes sense. It's still hard for my brain to think of everything in space as falling toward something. I would also assume that the speed to maintain orbit decreases the further out you get since the pull is less, I wonder if the moon affects how things orbit the earth.

Comment: @JcStraus "So your saying you don't float in space unless you're going fast?"* **Nope.** You could (if you wanted to waste enormous quantities of useful fuel) bring a space vehicle to relative rest a few hundred miles above the Earth and then let gravity take over and occupants would float in there as well up to the point when atmospheric drag started to get significant. The important condition is free-fall. You only need speed if you want to *stay* in free-fall. See also: "vomit comet" in which free-fall trajectories are established *despite* the atmosphere..

Comment: You haven't addressed the issue of whether the ISS astronauts continue to float when they get back to earth :-)

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem well, as they are carried from the Soyuz, I'd say the opposite happens: they become much heavier, and it takes a few weeks for the extra weight to disappear ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you bottled up some air in some region of space outside of earths atmosphere where space doesn't have much air in it and bring it back down, the bottle would implode at some point as you brought it down because of the pressure difference of the inside and outside air. The air becomes thicker as you move the bottle down, so you can think of the inside and outside of the bottle being bombarded by lots of balls. The outside has more air which also has more energy in it, so the outside will be 'beaten' more. At some point this 'beating' will be enough to implode the weakest part of the bottle.

Comment: What if the bottle were strong enough, like a round reinforced plexi glass container. Would gravity overcome the object inside or does the vacuum keep the item suspended.

Comment: Ok assuming the bottle is very strong, I'm thinking the bottle would rise due to its buoyancy and float at the point when gravity balances this force.  This is dependent on the bottle of course, if it is really light, then the buoyancy will always overcome gravity and it will escape the atmosphere !

Comment: Adding to my previous comment, this is the same as when you press a football under water. It wants to rise because of its buoyancy

Comment: @JcStraus, you are misunderstanding the roles of pressure and gravity. It is not pressure (or its absence in space) that causes the penny to float, it is the absence of gravity. Back on Earth, gravity returns and the penny drops, regardless of whether there is a vacuum inside the bottle. You are right that bottles can be created that will resist pressure and will not smash at one atmosphere of pressure (i.e. the pressure on Earth's surface).

Comment: Apologies @JcStraus I didn't see the part about the penny, This is an interesting question, and the answer is that gravity still works if there is something enclosing the mass! in the same way that when you are stood in an elevator, you still feel the pull of gravity, the penny inside the bottle doesn't care about its surroundings, it will respond in the same way to gravity, which only depends on the penny being some radial distance from the earth. I hope this clears things up for you